# Ubuntu 21.04 Black screen at login screen after system update

Tags: package-management, ubuntu-gnome, 21.04

After the last Ubuntu update black screen at login (Mouse pointer is visible).

I am getting 'Oh no! Something went wrong' screen on startx command:

[image: Oh no! Something went wrong screen]

I have tried update & dist-upgrade, tried to reinstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop, but broken packages error.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell : Depends: gnome-shell-common (= 40.2-0shemgpubuntu2) but 40.3-0shemgpubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

But no hold packages are there

```
$ sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gnome 40 was installed via [ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Eshemgp/+archive/ubuntu/gnome-40)

I have un-commented the following line in the sources list `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/shemgp-ubuntu-gnome-40-hirsute.list`

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/shemgp/gnome-40/ubuntu/ hirsute main
```

After this everything is working properly. Following commands fixed my issue

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop --reinstall
```